# Memory leak while using scheduled tasks - how to verify object's gc eligibility?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, scheduled-tasks

I have a small test program where some custom objects are put into a collection.
The custom objects are holding a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` member, which initializes a `scheduleAtFixedRate(<some quick task>, ...<every 1 min or so>)`. In other words each custom object in the collections is holding its own executor and scheduled future:

```
class A {
 private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
 private ScheduledFuture reoccurringTask = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                                                     () -> <some quick calc>,
                                                     1L, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

class B {
 List<A> list = new ArrayList<>(){{add(new A()); add(new A());}};

 // at some point
 list.remove(0);
 // In which case is the removed A object eligible for GC? (see questions below)
}
```

Now at some point based on some logic some of the `ScheduledFuture` of the custom objects are cancelled, but executor's `shutdown` method is not called, just its scheduled worker is done.

If I now clear the whole collection, assign it to null etc. I am not sure how is it about the gc eligibility of my custom objects:

- The custom objects, whose scheduled future are still active (not previously cancelled) are not eligible for gc, because the executor is running on its own, although there is no reference to the custom object from anywhere, or this is wrong?
- The custom objects, whose scheduled future are inactive (previously cancelled) are maybe eligible for gc, because there is no reference to the custom object from anywhere and the scheduled task is inactive, although the executor is not being shutdown, or this is wrong?
- All custom objects together with their members (executors and scheduled futures) are eligible for gc?

Would be nice to get some brief explanation. I tried to run gc in the hope to see which objects will be removed, but gc seems not to remove anything, probably because the test program is so small that gc does not want to start :)
I tried with Eclipse MAT, but could not find a proper way to identify which object is eligible for gc. Is there a simply wy to inspect a dump on objects eligible for gc?

Comment: None of the above. The tasks are GC-eligible when they have completed or been cancelled. The executors are GC-eligible when shutdown. The objects of class `A` are GC-eligible when their tasks are, as the tasks, being anonymous inner classes, hold references to their outer `A` instance.

Comment: @EJP, so to achieve the goal of preventing memory leaks, I must do all of the following (none can be skipped)? For each instance of A: 1. cancel scheduled task 2. shutdown executor 3. remove instance of A from list. Then each instance of A should be eligible for GC, right?

Comment: You don't need to cancel the task, unless you really don't want it to run next.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the clarification, nevertheless I would like to be able to verify this by a tool or something. If someone could point to a tool that highlights objects eligible for GC.